# Couldn't find needed information related to Connected App

Tags: api, connected-apps

Tried searching documentation for the below questions, but couldn't find answers for them.

- Can there be multiple connected apps in an developer org? And is there any limit to this number?
- Is there any REST Api to create connected app programatically?
- Are there any limitations associated with connected app? Like concurrency limits or other limits?
- Once the an access token is issued from developer org, using the connected app details. What is the validity of this access token in mins/hours? Can it be connected app specific or has to be same for all connected apps in the dev org?

Another question about which I have been pondering.

Say there are two developer orgs, Dev1-Org and Dev2-Org. Now an connected app has been created in Dev1-Org. Using the details of this connected app, and username and password of Dev1-Org, able to login into the org and perform CRUD operations on the data available. But how come using the same connected app details of Dev1-Org and username and password of Dev2-Org, able to login into Dev2-Org, and even access data of the Dev2-Org? Are the connected apps shared between dev orgs? How does this sharing happen?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes there can be multiple connected apps in an org, including a developer org. Have you tried to do this?

2) I haven't done this yet, but there is documentation [available](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_defining_remote_access_applications.htm#!)

3) The same governor limits will apply. Multiple users can use the same connected app to establish a connection to the org.

4) The validity of the access token can be controlled via the connected app. You could have it for 8 hours, but it will need to be [refreshed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_refresh_token_oauth.htm).

Comment: 1) Yes have tried that, by creating couple of connected apps. I am able to get access token using both of them. But the question was more on, if there is an limit on this number of apps?  4) I read somewhere that the validity of the access token is determined by the Timeout mentioned in Session Settings. Does that mean if it common to all the connected apps in the org? Hence wanted to know if there is timeout possible per app.  Thanks,  Nagesh